# ping works but curl does not

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I am trying to set up networking on my development server running Arch Linux, but something is amiss. I have enabled dhcpcd on all interfaces, and ping now works (including dns resolution), but `curl`/other TCP programs do not. Does anyone have any ideas for how to go about debugging this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: it can be lots of things, add `curl -v` output (note that it goes to `stderr` by default so you need to redirect it somehow, e.g. with `curl -v --stderr log.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

It was a very silly problem; the port in the office was configured for telephones (though labeled exactly the same as the adjacent ports, which actually work).